# Installation issues with OpenCV in ubuntu

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

I installed OpenCV for python2 by running:

```
`sudo apt-get install python-opencv`
```

But on running

```
import cv2
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

My friend did the same and it's working on his machine.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`?

Comment: Yes I did ! Same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I myself had the same issue, I solved it by first installing pip using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then i installed opencv by,

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Then i tried importing cv2 in python and it worked like a charm:

```
import cv2
```

NOTE: Import must be done inside the python shell